# When pausing game(using a bool and time.timescale) it doesn't pause the score counter

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

this will be my first question so go on easy on me please ;)

I'm building my first game in Unity using my limited knowledge, tutorials and troubleshooting on google but i can't seem to fix this issue

i have a script that counts score(with a GUIText) and another one to pause the game(using timescale) and you probably guessed it already but when i pause the game it doesn't pause the score.

```
 Script for Pausing:



     var isPaused : boolean = false;



        function Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown("p"))
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }

        function Pause()
        {
            if (isPaused == true)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                isPaused = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                isPaused = true;
            }
            }


Script for Score:


var Counter : int = 100000;   
var Substractor : int = 0;  
var Score : int = Counter - Substractor;   
function Update (
) {
    Score--;
    guiText.text = "Score: "+Score;
}
```

the score script is attached to a gameobject with a gui text and the script for pausing the game is attached to the player

another issue is that when i'm moving(using the arrow keys) then press pause and then unpause the player moves faster and unpredictable for a splitsecond but this is only when i press pause while pressing the arrow buttons when i only press pause  there is no issue, this is a small bugg that i'l try to fix myself, just thought i'd add it here for those that have an easy answer to this issue aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know this problem from other game frameworks and I've got no experiance with unity. But it should work the same way for unity as it does in other frameworks. You have two options:

---

Update is called after every rendering frame! So your `timescale` doesn'T influence how often update is called. Instead you have to find some `dt` or `deltaT` (don't know how it is called in unity and how to get it, but I mean the time, since unities the last call to update, please tell me in the comments, so I can edit this answer).

Then don't calculate your score like:

```
Score--;
```

but use something like:

```
Score -= 1 * dt
```

or

```
Score -= 1 * dt * Time.timeScale
```

(depending how exactly unity works)

---

alternatively you can sourround your update-block with some if-statement:

in Score:

```
function Update (
) {
   if (! isPaused()) { // not sure how this function / property is called in unity
      Score--;
      guiText.text = "Score: "+Score;
  }
}
```

Comment: i used Score -= 1 *Time.deltaTime and it worked. Thanks a lot for explaining why it didn't work and giving me a solution :)